# Bash and Python interaction

Tags: python, bash

I have a bash script that calls a Python one. The output of the python script is returned to bash with the command:

```
sys.exit(Main())
```

and is:

```
(1, 'STATUS', 0, '2015-09-18 14:08:13')
```

I would like to put each part of the string in a different variable in order to have:

```
var1=1, var2='STATUS', var3=0, var4='2015-09-18 14:08:13'
```

How can I do?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried already?

Comment: Are you aware that return code may be only a single number?

Comment: @ŁukaszR.: Weirdly, the arg of `sys.exit()` isn't a simple return code. The arg itself is printed to stderr, and if it's an integer then the shell gets that integer as a return code. Otherwise, the shell gets a return code of 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can print the variables in the python script in the format of bash env variables, and then [pipe that to source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176873/feed-source-command-with-a-pipe).

foo.py:

```
#!/bin/env python
vars = (1, 'STATUS', 0, '2015-09-18 14:08:13')
for i, value in enumerate(vars):
    print('VAR{}={}'.format(i, value))
```

bar.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
source <(python foo.py)
echo $VAR1
```

Comment: Oops! I should've noticed earlier that you need to quote the printed values to prevent word splitting in Bash. Eg `print("VAR{}='{}'".format(i, value))`. FWIW, a `start` arg can be given to `enumerate()` to start the numbers from a non-zero value, eg `enumerate(vars, 1)`. Actually, `vars` isn't a good variable name - it's a synonym for the `locals` built-in function.